# Access JSON element with parent name unknown

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api

I've got the same extact problem with [Access JSON item when parent key name is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608227/access-json-item-when-parent-key-name-is-unknown), but I work in python.

```
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "ramdom_number_here": {
                "pageid": ramdom_number_here,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Hello",
                "extract": "Hello world! Enchanté to meet you"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to get `extract` given the `random_number` changing every time?

p.s. It's quite a duplicate question and I'm not sure if the best thing is to open a new question or to answer under the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the key doesn't matter. You just want the (only) value stored in the `pages` object.

```
pages = d['query']['pages'].values()
x = list(pages)[0]['extract']
```

Comment: I was doing `d["query"]["pages"][0]["extract"]. Thanks