# Find parent name of a json attribute - unknown structure - Python

Tags: python, json, nested, attributes, parent

There is a JSON file with unknown structure.

I need to find an attribute of a known name in this file and, if it exists, return the name of its parent node, or nodes (if there are multiple instances of the attribute).

Example #1:

Input file:

```
{
    "attr1": {
        "attr2": {
            "attr3": "somevalue"
            "attr7": "someothervalue"
        }
    }
}
```

Attribute name: "attr7"

Expected return value: "attr2"

Example #2:

Input file:

```
{
    "some": {
        "deeply": {
            "nested": {
                "stuff": {
                    "array1": [
                        {"this":"value1"},
                        {"this":"value2"},
                        {"this":"value3"}
                     ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attribute name: "this"

Expected return value: "array1"

Example #3:
(similar to #2 but with a duplicate)

Input file:

```
{
    "some": {
        "deeply": {
            "nested": {
                "this": {
                    "array1": [
                        {"this":"value1"},
                        {"this":"value2"},
                        {"this":"value3"}
                     ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attribute name: "this"

Expected return value: "array1", "nested"

My starting point is:

```
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jsonFileName = "file.json"
    attributeName = "this"
    jsonFile = open(jsonFileName, "r")
    jsonData = json.load(jsonFile)
    # ???
```

I found this one: [Access JSON element with parent name unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730096/access-json-element-with-parent-name-unknown) but it is not really applicable in my case because they know the structure of their data and I don't.

Any hints?

Comment: You should really try to write some code. How do you think you could iterate over the object returned from `json.load()`?

Comment: Good hint, thanks. I actually wrote some code after publishing this question (with a help of a more experienced colleague) and it kind of works. It involves iterating over json elements, detecting whether they are lists or dicts, and some recursive logic. I am planning to publish an answer here once I get it to a more presentable shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with a bit of a back and forth with a more experienced [colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227606/piotr-rodak) I came up with the following solution:

```
def findKey(jsonData: json, keyName: str, accessPath: str):
    if isinstance(jsonData, str):
        return None
    for key in jsonData.keys():
        if key == keyName:
            return accessPath + f"/{keyName};"
        if isinstance(jsonData[key], list):
            for jd in jsonData[key]:
                fk = findKey(jd, keyName, accessPath + "/[]" + key)
                if(fk):
                    return fk
        elif isinstance(jsonData[key], dict):
            fk = findKey(jsonData[key], keyName, accessPath + "/{}" + key)
            if(fk):
                return fk
    return None
```